# How to add new rows to a dataframe in order to satisfy a condition in a column, and copying the rest of the columns

Tags: row, addition

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "client":[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],
        "month": [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2],
        "año:[2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017],
    "total": [25,30,5,40,6,55,25,85,4,9,5,40,6,55,25,85,4,9,10]
})
```

What I want is to have for each cliente rows for the 12 months of each year. For this new rows I want to fill the column total with 0 and copy the information from the rows of the same year and client.